# Passing scriplets data into CommandArgument and retrieve it in the C# server side when button event is fired

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have done this code so far and I was wondering if I am able to pass in `<% x.travelDetailsId %>` value to the C# when the button is clicked? (so when the button that has the id of 33, it will pass in 33. 'works something like every button has their own unique id so when clicked it will pass in their id') currently, it will just pass in a string `<%= x.travelDetails %>` instead of the value of the scripts. I have tried taking out the quotation but it doesn't work. ***not trying to use repeater here***

itineraryHomepage.aspx

[image]

itineraryHomepage.aspx.cs
(the `CommandArgument` is able to pass in details when the button is clicked, however, when I assign the script <%= x.travelDetailsId %> to the `CommandArgument` attributes, it will return as a string)

[image: picture of code for itineraryHomepage.aspx.cs]

Layout of the page: (example the itineraryid of 33 delete button is clicked. the button event thn will pass in 33 to the c# server side )

[image: picture of layout of the page]

Comment: If you want tighter control of your markup, you should consider ASP.NET MVC which has the Razor view engine. Far superior to Web Forms aspx.

Comment: I am currently working with ASP.net for my project, and I am not allowed to use ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: That statement doesn't really make sense. ASP.NET MVC is part of ASP.NET. Did you mean that you are restricted to using ASP.NET Web Forms only? If so, where are you going to school or working that they're restricting you to such an arcane and inefficient technology stack?

Comment: yu and i will glad to use MVC if i got a chance to but we are restricted to just asp.net web forms currently

Comment: Why do you have that space after `CommandArgument=` in the markup? There shouldn't be a space there.

Comment: its was previously shown to my group members to read easier.

Comment: It's invalid markup. You should remove it.